# Creating entity framework complex types of store procedures with oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures, complextype

I am using database first approach in asp.net MVC with Oracle and entity framework. I am unable to create complex types of store procedures. On clicking **Get Column Information** nothing is happening.

Kindly help me in creating complex types of store procedures using oracle and entity framework.

[image: On clicking Get Column Information nothing is happening.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on following link.

https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/2015/entityframework_linq_modelfirst/Entity%20Framework%20LINQ%20and%20Model%20First.html